# How to show ajax loading icon with Django EndlessPagination?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-endless-pagination

I'm using Django endless pagination

https://github.com/frankban/django-endless-pagination

Right now instead of showing a graphic loading icon it just shows the word "loading". Is it possible to show a graphic icon somehow? I don't see anything in the list of options to set a url for an icon.

```
        var defaults = {
        // Twitter-style pagination container selector.
        containerSelector: '.endless_container',
        // Twitter-style pagination loading selector.
        loadingSelector: '.endless_loading',
        // Twitter-style pagination link selector.
        moreSelector: 'a.endless_more',
        // Digg-style pagination page template selector.
        pageSelector: '.endless_page_template',
        // Digg-style pagination link selector.
        pagesSelector: 'a.endless_page_link',
        // Callback called when the user clicks to get another page.
        onClick: function() {},
        // Callback called when the new page is correctly displayed.
        onCompleted: function() {},
        // Set this to true to use the paginate-on-scroll feature.
        paginateOnScroll: false,
        // If paginate-on-scroll is on, this margin will be used.
        paginateOnScrollMargin : 1,
        // If paginate-on-scroll is on, it is possible to define chunks.
        paginateOnScrollChunkSize: 0
    },
```

Comment: Can you have an img element on the page and adjust the loadingSelector to include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In settings.py set the image here:

ENDLESS_PAGINATION_LOADING = ""

All the other options are listed here:

http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to override a template

endless/show_more.html - and put there loading.gif :)

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}
{% if querystring %}
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="endless_container">
        <a class="endless_more" href="{{ path }}{{ querystring }}"
            rel="{{ querystring_key }}">
            <button>Więcej</button></a>
        <div class="endless_loading" style="display: none;">
            <img src="{% static "img/ajax-loader.gif" %}"></div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```